# How sort HashMap<String,String> DESC

Tags: java, android, sorting

i get data from json and put in the HashMap and show in ListView Now i want sort desc data in this HashMap and show in ListVeiw

this is part of my code

```
for(int i=0;i<jmsg.length();i++){
    JSONObject c = jmsg.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
    String subj = c.getString(TAG_SUBJ);
    String text = c.getString(TAG_TEXT);

    Log.i("Ekhteraat app ControlPanel", id);

    HashMap<String,String> nnews = new HashMap<String,String>();

    nnews.put(TAG_ID,id);
    nnews.put(TAG_NAME,name);
    nnews.put(TAG_EMAIL,email);
    nnews.put(TAG_SUBJ,subj);
    nnews.put(TAG_TEXT,text);

    msgList.add(nnews);


    nText=nText + subj + "\n";

    tnews=tnews+1;

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            GetMSGActivity.this, msgList, R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_EMAIL,TAG_SUBJ,TAG_TEXT},
                            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.subj, R.id.text}
                    );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Can you please check how can sort it.

my data like this

> id,1
>
> name,sadegh
>
> email,sadegh@email.com
>
> subject,test
>
> text,hi this is test
>
> ---
>
> id,2
>
> name,rrr
>
> email,rrr@email.com
>
> subject,test
>
> text,hi this is test
>
> ---
>
> id,3
>
> name,lll
>
> email,lll@email.com
>
> subject,test
>
> text,hi this is test

**but** i want show here

> id,3
>
> name,lll
>
> email,lll@email.com
>
> subject,test
>
> text,hi this is test
>
> ---
>
> id,2
>
> name,rrr
>
> email,rrr@email.com
>
> subject,test
>
> text,hi this is test
>
> ---
>
> id,1
>
> name,sadegh
>
> email,sadegh@email.com
>
> subject,test
>
> text,hi this is test

Comment: Use `TreeMap`, not `HashMap`.

Comment: The keysets of HashMaps are unordered. Have a quick search on the difference of TreeMap/HashMap/LinkedHashMap as this question was asked before.

Comment: @runDOSrun,in the link sort by key,they have same key but i have part of data with not same key can see in post(edit post)

Comment: I guess you should stop using `Map` as an entity, create a proper class with relevant fields instead. And by the way you're not looking for having the data sorted but ordered the way the key/value pair was inserted, so use a `LinkedHashMap`, but again, please do not use `Map`s as entities.

Comment: Your edit is just confusing. You want to sort by key, yes? Then don't use a HashMap.

Comment: @runDOSrun,i have a for that each time put data with different key and add listview `nnews.put(TAG_ID,id);
nnews.put(TAG_NAME,name);
nnews.put(TAG_EMAIL,email);
nnews.put(TAG_SUBJ,subj);
nnews.put(TAG_TEXT,text);`

Comment: Maybe i put data in array then sort array

Comment: Never *once* have you said "I want to sort by name". That simple sentence is everything you needed. Next time, *take your time and try* formulating clear & structured sentences so people understand you. Put the names in an array + sort. Btw, Luiggi is right, you need a custom **class** for your json object not a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashMaps are unsorted by definition. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

If you need ordering, use one of Java's [SortedMaps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

> A Map that further provides a total ordering on its keys. The map is
>   ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a
>   Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time.

`java.util` has two standard implementations - [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).